# java.lang.NullPointerException form user input

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java.lang.class

Hey guys I'm trying to create a loop until a correct character choice is entered by the user. When I enter a wrong choice I get the error java.lang.NullPointerException. It might be with the way I'm inputing but I don't want to change that if I don't have to. choice is a private member of the class.

```
char wf() { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("What is your choice? (x/o)"); 
    choice = input.findInLine(".").charAt(0);

    while (choice != 'x' && choice != 'o') { 
        System.out.println("You must enter x or o!");
        choice = input.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
    }

    return choice; 
}//end wf
```

Comment: Is `findLineAt` returning `null`? If so, that's the problem, cause you call `charAt` right after. If `findLineAt` was `null`, you will not be able to call methods since there was no object to call methods from (instead there was null), hence the NPE.

Comment: Since it is clear that `findLineAt` returns `null` you only have to understand why. You can do that by reading the JavaDoc and by debugging this method, to see what happens there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function as below (I have tested this code):

```
char wf() { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("What is your choice? (x/o)"); 
    char choice = input.findInLine(".").charAt(0);

    while (choice != 'x' && choice != 'o') { 
        System.out.println("You must enter x or o!");
        choice = input.next().charAt(0);
    }

    return choice; 
}//end wf
```

Answer (score 1):

Check input.findInLine(".") to see if it null.  If you don't have the expected input, it won't return anything..

Answer (score 1):

change your code like below

```
char wf() { 
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("What is your choice? (x/o)"); 
if(input.findInLine(".") !=null){
choice = input.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
while (choice != 'x' && choice != 'o') { 
    System.out.println("You must enter x or o!");
    choice = input.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
 }
}
return choice; 
}//end wf
```

Comment: Can you explain why it should work, even though it doesn't?