# User based Multiplication Table

Tags: java, multiplication, netbeans-8

Hi I need help with my code. Im trying to make a user base input multiplication table using a Scanner and a method, but i dont know how to get the user base input from the main method to the method i created, here is what i have so far:

```
public static void multiplicationTable(int i){
for (int i=1;i<=size;i++){
for (int j=1;j<=size;j++)
System.out.print("\t"+i*j);
System.out.println(); }
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
System.out.println("This program displays a multiplication table.");
Scanner size = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
int n = size.nextInt ();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your codes are pretty closed. Please see below (I have tested the codes):

```
public static void multiplicationTable(int size) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
            System.out.print("\t" + i * j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("This program displays a multiplication table.");
    Scanner size = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
    int n = size.nextInt();
    multiplicationTable(n);
}
```

Comment: Rehman is right, but also the argument name of multiplicationTable() must be changed to "size" ("i" would be duplicated to the outer for loop variable "i").

Comment: also how can place a loop to tell the user to input a positive integer in case that the user puts a negative one over and over until the user inputs a positive one to run the file

Comment: Please refer to [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067801/java-lang-nullpointerexception-form-user-input/33067913?noredirect=1#comment53954191_33067913) for iteratively check user's input. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass like :

```
    System.out.println("This program displays a multiplication table.");
    Scanner size = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer: ");
    int n = size.nextInt ();
    multiplicationTable(n); \\ pass here
```